# Projective bundle associated to sum of trivial line bundles

Tags: vector-bundles

I am having some difficulty seeing that $P(1\oplus 1)=X\times S^{2}$. Here $1$ denotes the trivial (complex) line bundle over $X$, and $P$ indicates the projective bundle.

Comment: I don't get it. $1 \oplus 1$ is just $X \times \mathbb{R}^2$. So $P(1 \oplus 1)=X \times \mathbb{R}P^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The total space of a trivial complex line bundle over $X$ is effectively $X \times \mathbf{C}$; "effectively" because a trivial line bundle has no "natural" trivialization, while $X \times \mathbf{C}$ has the distinguished section whose value is $1$ at each point.

In the same sense, the total space of the direct sum of two trivial complex line bundles is $X \times (\mathbf{C} \oplus \mathbf{C}) \simeq X \times \mathbf{C}^2$. Projectivizing obviously gives a global product $X \times \mathbf{CP}^1$ because the overlap maps of the rank-two vector bundle can be taken to be constant (with value the identity matrix).

Comment: $S^2\cong{\Bbb{C}}P^1$ :D

Comment: Thanks. I got confused when I was thinking about it. I thought I would get $\mathbb{CP}^{2}$ instead of $\mathbb{CP}^{1}$.